# Convert .XML to HashMap

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

I have .xml file like this. i want convert this file to HashMap and reverse in Java. Could you please tell me how can i convert it to HashMap file? Thank you ...

### This is the .xml file:

```
<RelationShipTypes>
        <RelationShipType key="1" name="Organization Unit"/>
        <RelationShipType key="2" name="Employee"/>
        <RelationShipType key="3" name="Customer"/>
        <RelationShipType key="4" name="Supplier"/>
        <RelationShipType key="5" name="Agency"/>
        <RelationShipType key="6" name="Partner"/>
        <RelationShipType key="7" name="SALES AGENT"/>
        <RelationShipType key="8" name="End User"/>
        <RelationShipType key="9" name="Other"/>
    </RelationShipTypes>
```

### This is the code:

```
  public static Map<String, String> convertNodesFromXml(String xml) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        try {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.parse(is);
            return createMap(document.getDocumentElement());
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseDataLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseDataLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseDataLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> createMap(Node node) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.hasAttributes()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < currentNode.getAttributes().getLength(); j++) {
                    Node item = currentNode.getAttributes().item(i);
                    map.put(item.getNodeName(), item.getTextContent());
                }
            }
            if (node.getFirstChild() != null && node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                map.putAll(createMap(currentNode));
            } else if (node.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                map.put(node.getLocalName(), node.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **parse the XML first**. Try using **DOM parser** for the same. Google it you'll get sample code. Then you can populate the values in a **HashMap**. 
Here is [sample code.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: Obviously it wont work for your XML file. Please modify the code accordingly to get it working. This code will just provide the approach to go about writing XML parser. You wont get already cooked code on the web.

Comment: i write this Code.
where is the problem?

Comment: when " Document document = db.parse(is);" run, it show me a SAXException

Comment: Please paste the xml file as well.

Comment: I do not get any exception as such.